# No puedo pasar una consulta select del modelo al controlador

Tags: php, mvc, crud

Tengo un proyecto en PHP con MVC y estoy desarrollando la funcionalidad READ del CRUD. Realizo la conexión con la bbdd correctamente, e incluso si imprimo la consulta en el archivo del modelo la veo perfectamente, pero cuando la envío al controlador (con un return), no soy capaz de recibirla.
Dejo código...

ARCHIVO CARPETA MODELS (clientes.php)

```
public function readCliente(){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";

    $consulta = $this->db->query($sql);

    /* ESTE FOREACH SÍ IMPRIME
    foreach($consulta as $value){

        echo $value["id_cliente"] . " " . $value["nombreCliente"] . " " . $value["telefono"] . "<br>";

    }
    */

    //var_dump($consulta);

    return $consulta;  //ESTE RETURN NO ENVÍA AL CONTROLADOR, O EL CONTROLADOR NO RECIBE

    //$this->db->close();

}
```

ARCHIVO CARPETA CONTROLLERS

```
<?php

    require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/wbmm/models/clientes.php";

    $leerCliente = new Cliente();
    $leerCliente->readCliente();

    //ESTE FOREACH ME DICE QUE LA VARIABLE $CONSULTA NO ESTÁ DEFINIDA
    foreach($consulta as $value){

        echo $value["id_cliente"] . " " . $value["nombreCliente"] . " " . $value["telefono"] . "<br>";

    }

    //require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/wbmm/views/clientesRead.php";

?>
```

He hecho la prueba de imprimirlo en el controlador, aunque ya sé que luego debo pasarlo a la vista, que es donde realmente lo debo imprimir, pero estoy probando.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: El `$leerCliente->readCliente()` deberás asignarlo a una variable. Si quieres utilizar el mismo nombre que en el modelo (`$consulta`), bien. Si no,podría ser otro. Así que si queires seguir con el mismo sería... `$consulta = $leerCliente->readCliente();` En cualquier caso... date cuenta que estás leyendo muchos clientes y no sólo uno. Recomendaría poner nombres no ambiguos: por ejemplo `public function readCliente($id){` o bien `public function readClientesTodos(){`porque en este caso (el tuyo) devolverás un array de clientes y no uno solo, por lo que tendrás que hacer dos `foreach` anidados

Comment: Muchas gracias. Efectivamente me estaba olvidando de asignar la ejecución del método readCiente() a una variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un problema de concepto de ámbito de variables. Das por supuesto que si en el objeto de modelo Cliente() hay un `return $consulta`, esa variable va a existir al llamar al método que la devuelve, cuando no es así.

Si necesitas usar ese mismo nombre $consulta para recibir el return, puedes hacerlo así en tu controlador:

```
$consulta = $leerCliente->readCliente();
```

y de este modo **sí** que estas creando una variable llamada $consulta, que casualmente se llama igual que la que estás retornando desde **readCliente()**, dentro de un método del controlador, aunque no tiene porque, podría ser cualquier otro nombre de variable.

De este modo ya no te dará ese error, aunque es probable que aparezcan otros, pues no veo que **fetch** le haces a la consulta, solo el query, pero tampoco sabemos que es **$this->db** y que hace su método **query**.

Comment: Voy a probar con lo que me dices. Ya te cuento.

$this->db->query() es la llamada a la base de datos.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Perfecto, funcionando. Muchas gracias.